# Why innodb doesn't store geospatial data?

Tags: myisam

I am very curious.

I have business tables. Now I think I will have to create a separate table, location table. That separate table should be myisam.

But why would I do so?

Why can't innodb store points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [R-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) are not [B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree):

> For MyISAM tables, [SPATIAL INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) creates an R-tree index. For storage
>   engines that support nonspatial indexing of spatial columns, the
>   engine creates a B-tree index. A B-tree index on spatial values will
>   be useful for exact-value lookups, but not for range scans.

Adding a completely different storage structure for InnoDb is significant effort (much more than for MyISAM due to locking and recovery).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it can. But it doesn't support spatial indices on them, yet. See the official Mysql docs [Limits on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> InnoDB tables do not support spatial data types before MySQL 5.0.16. As of 5.0.16, InnoDB supports spatial data types, but not indexes on them.

Comment: What does it mean not supporting indexes on them? Does that mean finding 20 closest store is still going to be expensive?

Comment: Yes, finding closest store effectively requires spatial index (R-tree). Read the links from Remus answer. So, yes, it will be expensive.