# Can we use innodb to store latitutude and logitude and retrieve 20 closest points well?

Tags: innodb

I've heard that innodb [Why innodb doesn't store geospatial data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19240/why-innodb-doesnt-store-geospatial-data) store geospatial data but cannot index it.

Not really sure what it means. Is it a good idea to ask 20 closest businesses if point is stored in innodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient, but complex, solution:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng
(The design actually prefers InnoDB.)